# Is it acceptable for a server-based application installer to create a new group?

Tags: windows, security, installation, usergroups

We're building an application designed to run on Windows-based servers. One of the considerations we're looking into at the moment is how to control access to the application's GUI, which allows configuration and controls the "back end" services.

In order to secure the application properly, there are several objects which will need ACLs to be applied - files, directories, Registry keys, named pipes, services etc. We need to provide administrators with some way to configure those ACLs in order to limit access to authorized users only.

One approach we have considered is to create a tool which can modify the ACLs on all those objects simultaneously, but that would be a fair chunk of work and could be fragile.

The other possible approach we're looking at is to create a custom group (e.g. "My App Users") so we can give that group the appropriate rights to each object. This means that administrators will be able to add/remove authorized users by using familiar Windows group membership tools.

So: is creating groups at install time an acceptable thing to do, or is it likely to upset administrators? I'm more familiar with the UNIX world, to be honest, where server-based apps are more or less expected to create groups, but I'm uncertain of the etiquette in the Windows ecosystem.

Also: is there a better solution to this that I've missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is twofold - one technical, and one political.  Technically a local group is fine, you can add AD or domain users into a local group and everyone's happy.  In terms of whether an app should be messing with a server's security 'stance', the only reasonable answer is to pop up some kind of request telling the user what you are going to do and asking permission (make sure you also document the decision in some kind of log or entry).  This also addresses everybody's legal a$$ eg if they click "no, leave my app unsecured" and get hacked).

Taking a UNIX approach, you could tell the user what you need, suggest a local group (and give the user the chance to pick another local or domain/AD group).  Take a look at how (eg) Oracle installs on UNIX do it.

Since this is a server app and you might have to support silent/unattended install, make sure that the behavior can be specified in the install script and very, very sure that the behavior of the script is documented so that no one installs the program without realizing the change in security policy that the installer implements.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Based on your comments, I'm thinking the default should probably be to allow access only to the local Administrators group (on the assumption that members of this group can do pretty much whatever they like anyway). That avoids the "leave my app unsecured" problem.
As you say, making group creation/selection optional is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's perfectly fine to create a local group for this purpose.

Furthermore I have not been able to come up with a better solution after giving it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the implementation, groups could be the way to go.
But please keep in mind that the relevant ACLs on directories and the registry ought to be set. I do agree that setting them once to the group and then let access control be maintained by group memberships.
In regards to klausbyskov's answer, I think a local group could be fine, but consider using LDAP instead. From a security perspective you would detach the authentification process and let the Directory handle it; using kerberos.